# R double loop select output

Tags: r, loops, double

I think I have a quite straightforward and easy to answer question, but I cannot come up with a solution by myself.

I have one vector with 10 elements and I want to get a new vector which consists of the first element minus the second, the first element minus the third, and so on. However, in the same vector I would like to have also numbers for the second element minus the third, second element minus the fourth, etc. and also for the other elements.

In my opinion, I need two for loops for doing this, but with the after running the following script I get too much elements:

```
for (w in 1:test1){  
  for (u in 1:test1) {
     print(mean[[u]] - mean[[w]])  }}
```

Now I used the print command, but I want to assign the results to a vector.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ttt <- (1:5)^3
#[1]   1   8  27  64 125

result <- outer(ttt,ttt,"-")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0   -7  -26  -63 -124
#[2,]    7    0  -19  -56 -117
#[3,]   26   19    0  -37  -98
#[4,]   63   56   37    0  -61
#[5,]  124  117   98   61    0
```

Now select the elements you need (which is not entirely clear to me from the question).

Maybe you want this:

```
t(result)[lower.tri(t(result))]
[1]   -7  -26  -63 -124  -19  -56 -117  -37  -98  -61
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the function "outer".

Comment: @user2023167 `outer` is very usefull, but be warned that you can run out of memory easily if your vector is large.

Comment: that will probably cause some problems in my case, because it is part of a simulation study. Can give me an indication how "large" a large vector is?

Comment: A vector of length 1e4 gives a matrix of 0.7 GB. A bit larger and you run into problems on most systems and would have to use alternatives, which calculate only the upper triangle or don't hold the whole result in memory.